# How to project the $in operator as a boolean in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
feed = coll.aggregate([
    {'$project' :{'Upvoted' : 
                            {'Upvoters'  : {'$in' : [ObjectId(userid)]} }}},
    {'$match' :{ '$or': [ {"_id": ObjectId(userid) }, {"Friends": ObjectId(userid) } ] } },
    {'$unwind' : "$Wall" },
    {'$sort' :  { "Wall.Hotness" : -1 }},
    {'$limit' : numResults }] )
```

I'm trying to project whether a user has upvoted or not. I do this by checking if a user is in the upvoters list.  It errors saying invalid opererator $in currently.  Is there an alternative to in that returns a boolean in mongo?

Comment: Can you add a sample document, so we can see your document structure to better understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error trying to use `$in` with a `$project` because `$in` is only a valid operator for a `$match` pipeline stage.

I don't think you actually need an explicit "boolean" for your aggregate: you just want to match all documents where this property is true.

Example aggregate:

```
var currentUser = ObjectId("517ae8124bc9ade96ca6403f");
var numResults = 10;

db.feed.aggregate(

    // Find all posts that currentUser has upvoted
    { $match: {
        'Upvoters'  : currentUser
    }},

    // Unwind the wall messages
    { $unwind : "$Wall" },

    // Sort by hotness (descending)
    { $sort : { "Wall.Hotness" : -1 } },

    // Limit results
    { $limit : numResults }

)
```

Comment: Note: I'm not sure what your original match criteria was intended to capture: `{ $match :{ '$or': [ {"_id": ObjectId(userid) }, {"Friends": ObjectId(userid) } ] } }`. You could add a corrected version to the `$match`; perhaps you meant to find all posts upvoted by either a given user or their friends?