# MongoDB - Query to get items and also know if I voted them

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This question is related to this one: [simple voting system with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339233/simple-voting-system-with-mongodb/12339308)

I have a collection of items that can be up-voted or down-voted by users. I wonder how I can retrieve some items and at the same time know if I voted them up or down.

**Item collection contains items that are more or less like these:**

```
{
  _id:0,
  name:'Item 0',
  upVoters: [ 1, 2 ],
  downVoters: [ 3, 4 ]
}
{
  _id:1,
  name:'Item 1',
  upVoters: [ 1, 3 ],
  downVoters: [ 4 ]
}
{
  _id:2,
  name:'Item 2',
  upVoters: [ ],
  downVoters: [ 2 ]
}
```

That means that, for example, item 0 was up-voted by users with ids 1 and 2 and down-voted by users 3 and 4.

If I am user 2 and get those items, I want to know that I up-voted item 0, didn't vote item 1 and down-voted item 2.

How can I perform that query? I would like to do it with just one query if possible. I suppose I have to use aggregation but I can't find the way to do it.

**Expected result if I query items from the point of view of user 2:**

```
{
  _id:0,
  name:'Item 0',
  user_vote: 1
}
{
  _id:1,
  name:'Item 1',
  user_vote: 0
}
{
  _id:2,
  name:'Item 2',
  user_vote: -1
}
```

I can change the collection shape if it helps. For example, I could use a model similar to the one proposed in the question I link above.

**Alternative model:**

```
{
  _id:0,
  name:'Item 0',
  voters: [
    { id:1, vote:+1}, { id:2, vote:+1},
    { id:3, vote:-1}, { id:4, vote:-1}
  ]
}
{
  _id:1,
  name:'Item 1',
  voters: [
    { id:1, vote:+1}, { id:3, vote:+1},
    { id:4, vote:-1}
  ]
}
{
  _id:2,
  name:'Item 2',
  voters: [
    { id:2, vote:-1}
  ]
}
```

Thank you very much

-- Ferran

EDIT:

As I say in my comments, the solution I've found so far is to send 3 queries: one to get the up-voted items, another to get the down-voted and another to get the non-voted:

**A provisional solution to get items and votes for a user**

```
db.items.find({ upVoters:USER_ID })
db.items.find({ downVoters:USER_ID })
db.items.find({ upVoters:{$ne:USER_ID}, downVoters:{$ne:USER_ID} })
```

Comment: One solution I have found so far is to query 3 times. One to get the up-voted items, another to get the down-voted and a third to get the non-voted.

I comment about this on an answer by @Tamas.

Comment: It would also be great if I could reduce an array to a boolean, like it is proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240382/how-to-project-the-in-operator-as-a-boolean-in-mongodb. That way I could get a boolean for upVote and another for downVote.

Comment: I think I can't either use `$cond` like they do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868370/mongodb-push-a-computed-expression-in-a-group) because it seems `$cond` can't be used to check if a value is inside an array.

Answer (score 4):

If you use your second example as a schema, you could do aggregation like this:

```
db.coll2.aggregate([
   // Split items by vote
   {$unwind:"$voters"},
   // Set vote to "0" for votes the user didn't cast
   {$project:{"vote":{$cond:[{$eq:["$voters.id",2]},"$voters.vote",0]}}},
   // Sum the votes for each item for this user (will get rid of 0-vote if user actually voted)
   {$group:{"_id":"$_id", "vote":{$sum:"$vote"}}}])
```

to achieve the result you're looking for. One caveat with this is that
if there are no votes for an item, then the `$unwind` step will not
allow that document through the rest of the pipeline, so you won't
know that the given user hasn't voted for it. This would be a problem
also with trying to do an aggregation query on your first proposed
schema, since intuitively we'd have to `$unwind` on both `upVoters`
and `downVoters`, and if one of those arrays were empty, then the
document would not pass through the pipeline.

If you're trying to access what votes a user has cast often, then it
could be worth storing the votes in some way that allows you to build
an index for them on `user_id` and/or `item_id` (the aggregation query
above cannot take advantage of an index). You could store the votes in
their own collection, for example:

```
{
    item_id:0,
    user_id:1,
    vote:1
}
{
    item_id:0,
    user_id:4,
    vote:-1
}
{
    item_id:2,
    user_id:2,
    vote:-1
}
```

This allows you to pull the data you want without aggregation and
could be a much faster option, too, with indexes on `user_id` and
`item_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the top of my head, you would have to probably $unwind the upVoters and downVoters arrays and then also do a match, something along the lines of:

```
db.votes.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$upVoters"},
  {$group: {"_id": "upVoters"}},
  {$match:{"_id.upVoters": {"$in": [2]}}}
])
```

(I'm about 99% sure that you'll need to rework that a bit :) )

Comment: Thanks, but I think that query is getting the items that the user up-voted. Then you will have to send another query to get the down-voted items and another to get the non-voted items. In fact, you can do that without aggregation: `db.items.find({upVoters:2})`. So far is the best solution I've found, although I don't like it much.